# Adding button to safari in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is it possible to add a button on the Safari browser of iPhone? Actually I want to create an iPhone app and when it install, it will automatically add a button to the iPhone safari. And then open safari there should be a button. I'm now wondering that it is possible or not. Please let me know your thoughts..

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, this not possible. There is nothing you can do to change the appearance or function of Safari. The only thing you can is register an URL handler so your app gets started when an URL of a certain scheme (`yourapp://someaction`) is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible using public APIs. Safari is an app provided by Apple and they wouldn't want people customizing it or making changes to it. So "No its not possible" AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

No you can't mess with the Safari it is inbuilt if you really want to do this then you have to jailBreak your iphone check cydia

Comment: so is it possible to add a button on safari, if the iphone is a jailbroken one?